# Is duplicate notification identifier safe in APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

According to [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) for APNS, we identify a message by notification identifier in it.

As it's our responsibility to decide the value of notification identifier, we can and  unavoidably will have it duplicated. In consideration of the error-response packet from APNS, I doubt whether it's safe to have duplicate notification identifier.

And here is my question:

- Q1: Is it safe to have the same **notification identifier** for the same **device token**?
- Q2: If the answer of Q1 is no, what about difference **device token** ?
- Q3: Is it safe to have the same **notification identifier** from difference **connection**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification identifier should be unique for each notification you send to APNS through the same socket. This way, if you read an error response from that socket, you'll know which message caused the error (and if the error type is invalid device token, you'll be able to identify the invalid token and delete it).

Therefore you should reuse the notification identifiers only when openning a new socket. If you have multiple sockets open at the same time, they should either use different notification identifiers, or if they don't, you have to be able to identify a notification based on the notification identifier + the socket.

As for your 3 specific questions :

Q1 : no, because if you sent two message to the same token and one of them had an error other than invalid device token, you won't be able to know which of the two messages caused the error. You also won't be able to know which messages need to be resent.

Q2 : no, for the same reasons as Q1, and in addition, if you get an error of invalid device token, you won't be able to know which device token is invalid.

Q3 : I'm not sure what you mean by different provider. If you refer to different servers managing different connections to APNS and sending notifications to the same app, the answer is yes, since the response received on a given socket contains the identifier of a message previously sent via that socket.

Comment: Is it possible that when I have multiple sockets, a notification is sent in one socket, and the error-responce for it is received in another socket? For example, notification A is sent in socket A, and the responce for A is received from socket B?

Comment: @kelvinhust No, that's not possible. `If you send a notification that is malformed or otherwise unintelligible, APNs returns an error-response packet and closes the connection.` This implies the response is sent on the same connection, right before it is closed.

Comment: I have changed *provider* to *connection* in Q3. Tnahks for your detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The notification identifier is only for you to distinguish between the different notifications you send.

The [push notification payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html) has no property to identify notifications - it has to be a custom property you send from your server to identify your own notifications. So the answer to Q1 is yes!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, we can have it duplicated. But I wanna know whether it's **SAFE** to do that or what situation I need to consider.

Comment: It depends on your application. Is the notification unique to a user? Push Notifications are not meant to be used for data delivery - they are only meant to inform the user that there is data to be fetched, so I can't think of scenarios where your notification identifier (your custom way to identify notifications) duplication would be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Notification identifier helps to identify your application that what kind of notification it is. So it is safe to have same notification identifier for same device token. So Q2, is not a question now. For Q3, it is fairly possible to have same notification identifier for different provider.

Comment: I think you confuse notification identifier with application identifier. The notification identifier is the item we can add to each notification. Looking forward to your advanced answer. ;)